# Executing C++ program on Geany

Tags: 12.04, command-line, kubuntu, c++, geany

I recently installed Kubuntu 12.04 LTS and I'm fairly new to Geany. I've used it on other computers but never installed it myself until now.
Now, I have C++ code that I've run on other machines (also on Geany), so I know it's not the code's fault.

I have installed all the packages I think are needed and here's the situation:

- Using Geany I can compile and build the code;
- Executable runs perfectly if run by terminal (Konsole);
- If I try to run using Geany (that rocket button or shortcut key), it opens a terminal window and shows just a "$". The title of the window is "sh - Konsole";
- It also runs ok if I run it on the terminal on Geany's application, so it seems I really need to enter the command;
- I've checked the build properties and it seems fine. There's "./%e" on the execute command.

This is the result of running the program by clicking the rocket button or pressing F5:

http://imageshack.com/a/img547/2711/ik7q.png

[SOLUTION]: Edit>Preferences>Tools and set Terminal to "konsole --workdir . -e sh -c"
Thank you all. Every answer was appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to identify a root cause, but I confirmed the same behavior in a Kubuntu 12.04 virtual machine and it seems to be an issue specific to the use of Konsole as the default x-terminal-emulator.

As a workaround, you can try setting a different terminal emulator in geany explicitly using `Preferences --> Tools --> Terminal` e.g.

[image]

You may need to install the `xterm` package if you have a pure Kubuntu system. This [bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/geany/bugs/734/) suggests another workaround.